# Finding indexes for use with np.ravel

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, indexing

I would like to use np.ravel to create a similar return structure as seen in the MATLAB code below:

```
[xi yi imv1] = find(squeeze(imagee(:,:,1))+0.1);
imv1 = imv1 - 0.1;
[xi yi imv2] = find(squeeze(imagee(:,:,2))+0.1);
imv2 = imv2 - 0.1;
```

where imagee is a matrix corresponding to values of a picture obtained from imread().
so, the(almost) corresponding Python translation is:

```
imv1=np.ravel(imagee**[:,:,0]**,order='F')
```

Where the bolded index splicing is clearly not the same as MATLAB. How do I specify the index values in Pythonic so that my return values will be the same as that found in the MATLAB portion? I believe this MATLAB code is written as "access all rows, columns, in the specified array of the third dimension." Therefore, how to specify this third parameter in Python?

Comment: Other than the difference between 0 and 1-based indexing, the order is the same.  `imagee(:,:,1)` in matlab is equivalent to `imagee[:,:,0]` in numpy.

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve indexes, I usually use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Here's an example: You have a 2 dimensional array

```
a = np.asarray([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
```

and want to get the indexes where the values are above a threshold, say 2. You can use np.where with the condition a>2

```
idxX, idxY = np.where(a>2)
```

which in turn you can use to address a

```
print a[idxX, idxY]
>>> [3 4 5]
```

However, the same effect can be achieved by [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
print a[a>2]
>>> [3 4 5]
```

This works on ravel'ed arrays as well as on three dimensional. Using 3D arrays with the first method however will require you to foresee more index arrays.